# UltiSnips: snippets not expanding

Tags: neovim, filetype-tex, plugin-ultisnips, plugin-vimtex

This is a noob question. I just installed UltiSnip to make use of the TeX snippets. Here is the relevant part of my `init.vim`:

```
" Specify a directory for plugins (powered by vim-plug)
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

" Make sure you use single quotes
 Plug 'lambdalisue/suda.vim'
 Plug 'powerman/vim-plugin-ruscmd'
 Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
 Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
 Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips'
 Plug 'honza/vim-snippets'
 Plug 'dart-lang/dart-vim-plugin'
 Plug 'natebosch/vim-lsc'

" Initialize plugin system
call plug#end()

" UltiSnips group
" Trigger configuration. Do not use <tab> if you use https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<c-b>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-z>"
```

The edited file extension is `tex`. I presume that it's enough to write `table` in edit mode and push . It's just a tab entered. My research shows that 'not working' is a quite common problem, but no reasonable way of troubleshooting is suggested, just obscure bits and loose ends. I tried `let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=["UltiSnips"]` and `let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=[$HOME.'/.vim/plugged/vim-snippets/UltiSnips']`, to no avail. `:UltiSnipsAddFiletypes` manually, the same. The docs are big on features, but way too concise on getting started.

`.vim` directory is shared via symlink, no trouble so far:

```
$ ln -s /home/user/.vim /home/user/.local/share/nvim/site
```

Any ideas?

UPD:

Oh, sorry. It turned out that with

```
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=[$HOME.'/.vim/plugged/vim-snippets/UltiSnips']
```

and *after* manual intervention

```
:UltiSnipsAddFiletypes tex
```

it starts breathing. What am I still missing?

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/issues/824). Of extensions, it honors only `*.latex`. Fortunately, if the file contains a preamble (`\documentclass{}` will do), it is honored on loading.

Comment: sounds like you can self-answer then?

Comment: Well, almost so. The [known issue](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/issues/824) mentions also a workaround of sorts, which I cannot fathom, as a noob :)

Comment: I do not know exactly what your problem is. As you have added the neovim tag I assume it does not work for neovim and you are re-using your old vim configuration since you use at two positions `~/.vim` paths. Why is then `~/.vim` a symlink to neovim? I would guess it should be the other way around. neovim stores its `init.vim` in `~/.config/neovim/init.vim`. I have added `let g:tex_flavor='latex'` to my vimrc so  that an empty `.tex` is treated as a latex file and not as a plaintex file. This also affects which snippets are available.

Comment: I'd recommend that you simplify your configuration in a first step by using a fresh configuration for neovim. If it works you can try symlinking things to have the same config for neovim & vim.

Comment: It is not all that bad. The preamble approach works and is reasonably convenient. I'm talking about a "workaround" at the end of the [known issue](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/issues/824). They suggest `plaintex.snippets` and `extends tex`, and I can't guess what it is all about.